# Where is the documentation for BigCommerce js sdk?

Tags: bigcommerce

The documentation for [building an application for BigCommerce](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/getting-started/building-apps-bigcommerce/building-apps) mention 
a [JavaScript SDK](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/getting-started/building-apps-bigcommerce/building-apps#building-apps_session-timeouts).

A single callback is mentioned, as part of the init method.

```
Bigcommerce.init({
      onLogout: callback
});
```

1. Where is the rest of the documentation for this library located at?
2. Is this library in a repository in the [BigCommerce github organization](https://github.com/bigcommerce/)?

Comment: I also search a lot but i didn't find anything. I collect product info, blog, shop info via php curl api call.

Comment: @JakirHossen I agree. The wealth of information you can access about the product catalog from the Client API in Shopify https://help.shopify.com/en/api/custom-storefronts/storefront-api/reference is epic. Wish BigCommerce had this...

Comment: Stay tuned @JJS--we're working on something similar. Here's a signup sheet if you're interested in early access or contributing feedback to the design process: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdAnU-CkraKwisJNsZRshbSyJafa65qV1ozgGHyYG73K29EYA/viewform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK does sit on a private BigCommerce GitHub repo and there's no additional documentation at this time, although we can augment what's there. The SDK exists to provide a single callback that app creators can use to handle control panel logouts-it doesn't do anything else. Probably something we can audit to see if it's possible to make it public, but the project is pretty static (meaning we update for maintenance/security, but no planned functional updates).